# file_get_contents() with images from a url and save them in zip

Tags: php, zip, file-get-contents

How can I cause file_get_contents() to get images from url and output them as a zip file.
e.g

```
http://example.com/image1.jpg
http://example.com/image1.jpg
http://example.com/image1.jpg
```

When retrieve with file_get_contents it'll store in a string, Now how can I convert this string into .zip.

it is to be cleared here that Images urls are being extracted from encoded json.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
copy('http://example.com/image1.jpg', '_tmp/image1.jpg')
copy('http://example.com/image2.jpg', '_tmp/image2.jpg')
...
zip( _tmp );
delete( _tmp );
```

Comment: Nice approach, As I have to do this for every user that is downloading. So basic question is how much load it causes on server?

Comment: In this case you should make a cache with association: `list of required files` => `zip archive name` so you'll be able to deliver the zip without creating it again everytime. Now, it all depends on your [imagesSize] x [imagesNumber] => copy files + the zip action. The [folderDelete] should be almost instant (unless you have more than 10-20 files in it).

Comment: There is a lil problem over here, this copy() function is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php

$files = array(
        'http://flask.pocoo.org/static/logo/flask.png',
        'http://flask.pocoo.org/static/logo/flask.pdf');

function create_zip(array $files, $destination='img.zip'){
    $zip = new ZipArchive();    
    $zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
    foreach($files as $file){
        print $file;
        if(copy($file, basename($file))){   
            print 'Successfully Copied ';
            if(file_exists(basename($file))){
                $zip->addFile(basename($file));
            }
        }else{
            print 'Failed to copy !!!';
        }
    }   
    $zip->close();
}

create_zip($files, 'testing.zip');
```

Comment: It gives me failed to copy for both files

Comment: There could be a couple of reasons why this might not work: 1) No permission to your target folder. 2) Missing Images from your source server. 3) Bad directory name, in your case _tmp should be fine. can you please put ini_set('track_errors', 1); at the beginning of the function and where it fails put : echo $php_errormsg; and see why is it failing. Hope it helps